# Monster Trading Cards

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I created this puzzle for an escape room type game. You find these 12 monster cards that are the clue to open a three digit combination lock:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What three digit number can you get from the cards?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what the numbers are (although the first two could be in either order), I just can't figure out how to r13(anghenyyl beqre gur pneqf fb gung gurl perngr gurfr ahzoref. V whfg qvq vg ol wvtfnj chmmyvat naq nz gelvat gb erirefr-ratvarre gur beqre.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is :

> 327

How can you find it too ?

> On each of the cards, some characteristics are the exact same as others. **e.g.** *Hapharis* has the same **stamina** as *Phytix*, the same **intelligence** as *Perilos* and the same **size** as *Quorup*. This creates a mesh of creatures, following the links !
>  Any monster that has the same value as another monster is then linked to that monster, creating a nice graph of all the monsters in a noticeable pattern. (**e.g.** *Hapharis* is now linked to *Phytix*, *Perilos* and *Quorup*.)

Once you did, you should obtain this :

> `Phytix ----- Hapharis ----- Quorup ---- Lalaris ---- Occalia ----- Bolix`
>   `|            |             |            |            |            |`
> `Megamox ----- Perilos ---- Vesperto ---- Slima --- Pertroklops --- Kugala`

The order they are placed in is not arbitrary, but this leads to the final part of the puzzle !

> About time to look at those pesky card corners  :
> All cards have a grid, 2 by 3, with black & white squares. All are similar, except a special one, *Kugala*, who contains a key to solve the placement easily !
>
> Thanks to the graph we already created linking all the cards with each other, we can see that it follows the same pattern as the grid, and surprise, *Kugala* is already in the bottom right corner ! (well, I made it that way, since I had the graph made for solving the puzzle...)
> This means we simply have to fill a big grid with all our 2 by 3 grids, and voila :
>
>  [image]
>  To help see that *Kugala* is a special card, it is also *foiled*, which is a nice touch ;)

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely right! Well done!